# ifelse statement don't work with a date

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have dataframe and want to recode the date that I can compare experiments in the future. But it dont work to recode the date with the if-statement. maybe there is hint to do this.

```
test <- data.frame(StartDate = c(rep("2015-02-16", 5), rep("2015-02-17", 5), rep("2015-02-23", 5), rep("2015-02-24", 5)),
                   response = sample(1:10,20,rep=TRUE)*7)



test$StartDate <- strptime(test$StartDate, format="%F")

test$day <- test$StartDate$mday
test$experimentday <- ifelse( (test$day == 16), 1, NA)
test$experimentday <- ifelse( (test$day == 17), 2, NA)
test$experimentday <- ifelse( (test$day == 23), 1, NA)
test$experimentday <- ifelse( (test$day == 24), 2, NA)

    StartDate response day experimentday
1  2015-02-16       35  16            NA
2  2015-02-16       35  16            NA
3  2015-02-16       63  16            NA
4  2015-02-16       63  16            NA
5  2015-02-16       21  16            NA
6  2015-02-17       70  17            NA
7  2015-02-17       42  17            NA
8  2015-02-17       14  17            NA
9  2015-02-17       42  17            NA
10 2015-02-17       70  17            NA
11 2015-02-23       49  23            NA
12 2015-02-23       21  23            NA
13 2015-02-23       42  23            NA
14 2015-02-23       14  23            NA
15 2015-02-23       21  23            NA
16 2015-02-24       56  24             2
17 2015-02-24       42  24             2
18 2015-02-24       42  24             2
19 2015-02-24       21  24             2
20 2015-02-24        7  24             2
```

Also other variations don't work

```
ifelse( test$day == 16, test$experimentday==1, test$experimentday==NA)

if(test$day == 16) {test$experimentday2 <- 1} 
else {test$experimentday2 <- NA}

if(test$day == 16) test$experimentday3 <- 1 
else test$experimentday3 <- NA
```

Comment: Hmm what's not working? Maybe you want to nest the `ifelse`s like `ifelse( (test$day == 16), 1, ifelse( (test$day == 17), 2, NA))` or use `switch` instead?

Comment: like @lukeA suggested, you should try: `test$experimentday <- sapply( as.character(test$day), switch, "16"=1,"17"=2,"23"=1,"24"=2)` or `test$experimentday <- ifelse(test$day %in% c(16, 23), 1, ifelse(test$day %in% c(17, 24), 2, NA))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is doing just what you tell it to.  The last line of your code,

```
test$experimentday <- ifelse( (test$day == 24), 2, NA)
```

sets the values of `experimentday` to 2 if `day` is 24, and sets all other values of `experimentday` to NA, effectively undoing the work of your previous lines of code.  You might want to try something like this, instead:

```
oldvalues <- c(16, 17, 23, 24)
newvalues <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
test$experimentday <- newvalues[match(test$day, oldvalues)]
```